# Odd result when doing simple math

Tags: swift, math

My code is

```
let m = 39
let maxPower = pow(3.0, Double(m))

if (Int(maxPower) % 3) == 0 {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

Why does it return false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the precision of `Double` in Swift (and of floating point numbers in general). Running

```
let power = pow(3.0, Double(39))
print(power)
```

will print **4.05255515301898e+18**, but the actual value of 3<sup>39</sup> is **4.052555153018976267e+18**, or **4052555153018976267** (notice the 76267 at the end)

When running

```
let mod = 4052555153018976267 % 3
```

The value is as expected, 0. As pointed out by [rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff), the actual stored value of the double is **4052555153018976256**. When running

```
let mod = 4052555153018976256 % 3
```

the result is 1, which is what you experience. This is why `value` is equal to 1 when running

```
let value = pow(3.0, Double(39)) % 3
```

Comment: It's clearer if you write it in normal (non-scientific) notation. The correct result is 4052555153018976267, but the nearest `Double` is 4052555153018976256.

Comment: `pow` returns 4052555153018976256, not 4052555153018976000.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks, I added that to the answer. I also made it a little more clear that I wasn't talking about the actual value, but rather the value that is printed

Comment: let power = pow(3.0, Double(39)); print(power)；will print 4.05255515301898e+18

Comment: @Utopia I just tested that and got the same result - I was actually using the value that the playground showed, assuming that it would be the same. That's really interesting... I'll edit the answer to use that value, though

Comment: @Jojodmo let maxPower = pow(3.0, Double(39)); print(maxPower); When I run these code, the printed result is 4.05255515301898e+18, but the value show in the right of playground is 4.052555153018976e+18 http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/82a49beegw1f1rlq302klj20nw00raa4.jpg

Comment: @Utopia That's the same result I get. It's probably due to some rounding error in the playground - it has no effect on the fact that the double is actually equal to 4052555153018976256, though.

Comment: @Jojodmo I use the code: let power = (NSDecimalNumber(double: 3).decimalNumberByRaisingToPower(39)).integerValue; it can work.

Comment: @Utopia In the event of doing 3^39, NSNumber will return the correct value. NSNumber's precision is not unlimited, though; for example, doing 3^50 will not yield the correct result. Also, using `.integerValue` will not work with large numbers such as 3^40 due to the bit length of integers. Your best bet for any large exponents will still be a third-party class

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you ran into a limit.

Put this in a playground and you will see that it works up until m is 37 or higher.

```
func testIt(m: Int, value: Double) -> Bool {
    let maxPower = pow(value, Double(m));
    if (Int(maxPower) % 3) == 0 {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

testIt(3, value: 3.0)  // true
testIt(4, value: 3.0)  // true
testIt(5, value: 3.0)  // true
testIt(6, value: 3.0)  // true
testIt(35, value: 3.0) // true
testIt(36, value: 3.0) // true
testIt(37, value: 3.0) // false
testIt(38, value: 3.0) // false
testIt(39, value: 3.0) // false
testIt(40, value: 3.0) // crash
```

Comment: Can I think it as a bug of Swift ?

Comment: @Utopia No, it would not be a bug in swift - it is something that is present in floating-point numbers in all programming languages, you'll have to use some type of BigDecimal class. As far as I know, Swift doesn't have any built-in ones, but there are a lot of these on github which can provide very, very high levels of precision